# What locals can be injected into a controller besides $scope?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-directive, angular-controller

Things in Angular can be injected with dependencies. But, injecting `$scope` into a directive won't work for example. Is there a concrete list of what is injectable into a controller or what isn't? What is injectable into a directive and what isn't? What is injectable into a service and what isn't? Etc? A comprehensive list of injectable/not injectable all in one place? The docs seems to have this info spread around, but it's hard to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

You can read everything in the docs. In case you mis-typed your controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('controllerName', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Your controller logic
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The controller is injectable (and supports bracket notation) with the following locals:

- `$scope` - Current scope associated with the element
- `$element` - Current element
- `$attrs` - Current attributes object for the element
- `$transclude` - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-controller-).